# One to one correspondence between transcendental and uncomputable numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, computability, transcendental-numbers

I know that both sets are uncountable infinite but the transcendentals are not a subset of the uncomputables. I don’t know if there exist uncomputable numbers that are not transcendental. But my question is whether the two sets have the same cardinality.

Comment: $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: An algebraic number is always computable, hence an uncomputable number must be transcendental.

Comment: Since both all real numbers and all transcendental numbers have the same cardinality, and the uncomputable numbers are in between, they also have it, see [Schröder–Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem).

Comment: @Conifold This argument is not valid. The set of the transcendental numbers is NOT a subset of the set of the uncomputable numbers. There are transcendental computable numbers.

Comment: @Peter: But the opposite argument *is* valid. Any non-computable real *is* transcendental. And since there are only countably many computable numbers...

Comment: An algebraic number is the zero of some polynomial say over the reals. But can we always compute the zeros of such a polynomial effectively?

Comment: @Peter I do not follow. Uncomputable numbers contain transcendental ones, and are contained in the real ones. Computable transcendental numbers are moot.

Comment: @Wuestenfux For computable/non-computable numbers it plays no role how difficult the calculation is.

Comment: At Peter: Because of what? Even if you know that the zeros exist in the algebraic closure, you need an effective method to find them.

Comment: @Conifold Your argument was that the non-computable numbers are between the reals and the transcendentals. But the transcendental numbers are not a subset of the non-computable numbers. Or what else did you mean with "between" ?

Comment: @Wuestenfux To clarify what "computable" means : A number is computable if there is an algorithm that can calculate arbitary many digits of the number. If we insist of computing the number EXACTLY, even a number like $\pi$ would be non-computable. If a number is algebraic, such an algorithm must exist.

Answer (score -1):

Here

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number

under "properties" it is stated the the set of computable numbers is countable.

Hence, the set of uncountable numbers must be uncountable infinite and hence have the same cardinality as the set of transcendental numbers which is uncountable infinite as well.